# app.js did not work in backbone.js + require.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I configured `main.js` file like this :

```
requirejs.config({
enforceDefine: true,
paths: {
    "jquery": "libs/jquery/jquery-min",
    "underscore": "libs/underscore/underscore-min",
    "backbone": "libs/backbone/backbone-min"
},
shim: {
    "underscore": {
        deps: [],
        exports: "_"
    },
    "backbone": {
        deps: ["jquery", "underscore"],
        exports: "Backbone"
    }
}
});

define(["jquery", "underscore", "backbone","reveal"],
function ($, _, Backbone,Reveal){
    console.log("$: " + typeof $);
    console.log("_: " + typeof _);
    console.log("Backbone: " + typeof Backbone);
}
);
```

The console is print out :

```
$: function
_: function
Backbone: object
```

So I supposed that `require.js` is working in my project.

This is what I did in `app.js` file :

```
define(["jquery", "backbone", "router"], function($, Backbone, Router) {
   $(document).ready(function(){
      alert(1);
   });
   var initialize = function(){
      Router.initialize();
   }
   return {
      initialize: initialize
   };
});
```

But the alert did not show when I browser my `index.html` file nor my router.

Any idea please. Thanks.

Comment: Did you put your <script> tag inside <body> or <head> element?

Comment: @enr.code I put `<script data-main="webcore/main" src="webcore/libs/require/require.js"></script>` in <head>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not loading `app.js` anywhere.

Try loading it in your `main.js`:

```
define(["jquery", "underscore", "backbone","reveal", "app"],
function ($, _, Backbone,Reveal, App){
    console.log("$: " + typeof $);
    console.log("_: " + typeof _);
    console.log("Backbone: " + typeof Backbone);
}
);
```